# React native handling html p tags

Tags: react-native

I have a screen that displays article information thats been pulled from a Wordpress API call and returns json (inclusive of all its lovely HTML tags).

```
<Text style={styles.summary}>{htmlRegex(item.content.rendered)}{"\n"}{Moment(item.date, "YYYYMMDD").fromNow()}</Text>
```

I have a function that strips out all of the HTML tags, tidies up any unicode, etc...

```
function htmlRegex(string) {
    string = string.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")
    string = string.replace(/&hellip;/g,"...")
    let changeencode = entities.decode(string);
    return changeencode;
  }
```

The challenge is that the

tags returned in the content appear to be causing odd line spacing issues, as shown in the screen grab;

[image: t]

The content.rendered contains;

```
rendered: "
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><img data-attachment-id="655" data-permalink="https://derbyfutsal.com/derby-futsal-club-women-name-change-june20/" data-orig-file="https://derbyfutsal.files.wordpress.com/2020/06/derby-futsal-club-women-name-change-june20.png" data-orig-size="1024,512" data-comments-opened="1" data-image-meta="{&quot;aperture&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;credit&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;camera&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;caption&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;created_timestamp&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;copyright&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;focal_length&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;iso&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;shutter_speed&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orientation&quot;:&quot;0&quot;}" data-image-title="derby-futsal-club-women-name-change-june20" data-image-description="" data-medium-file="https://derbyfutsal.files.wordpress.com/2020/06/derby-futsal-club-women-name-change-june20.png?w=300" data-large-file="https://derbyfutsal.files.wordpress.com/2020/06/derby-futsal-club-women-name-change-june20.png?w=730" src="https://derbyfutsal.files.wordpress.com/2020/06/derby-futsal-club-women-name-change-june20.png?w=1024" alt="" class="wp-image-655" srcset="https://derbyfutsal.files.wordpress.com/2020/06/derby-futsal-club-women-name-change-june20.png 1024w, https://derbyfutsal.files.wordpress.com/2020/06/derby-futsal-club-women-name-change-june20.png?w=150 150w, https://derbyfutsal.files.wordpress.com/2020/06/derby-futsal-club-women-name-change-june20.png?w=300 300w, https://derbyfutsal.files.wordpress.com/2020/06/derby-futsal-club-women-name-change-june20.png?w=768 768w" sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px" /></figure>



<p>Derby Futsal Club Ladies’ team are renamed Derby Futsal Club Women.</p>



<p>The change in name reflects Derby Futsal’s work in developing all aspects of futsal on and off the court.</p>



<p>It reflects the way the league (FA National Futsal Women’s Super Series), the players, the fans and the management refer to the game.</p>



<p>Hannah Roberts, Derby Futsal Club Women captain, believes “the change from Ladies to Women’s is a subtle but important one. Many professional sports teams have moved towards ‘Women’s’ in the last five years in order to stay modern and in touch, and as a forward-thinking club it’s important for Derby Futsal to do the same. We’re making so many strides in our community work and marketing, and this name change is another step forward to the future for the club”.</p>



<p>Derby Futsal Club Women first team coach, Matt Hardy feels this name change signifies evolution for the team; “the future of the women’s game both at Derby and nationally is looking bright. So it’s only right that we have a name that is modern, and inline with the national game”.&nbsp;</p>



<p>This news follows similar moves in professional football. Chelsea, Manchester City and Arsenal have all renamed their women’s team recently. It is something Professor Kath Woodward from the Open University, an expert on sociology and sport agrees with, “the use of ladies suggests a physical frailty and need for protection&#8221;.</p>



<p>Alex Scott, former Arsenal Women captain, adds: &#8220;the term &#8216;Women&#8217;s&#8217; delineates between men and women without as many stereotypes or preconceived notions and it is in keeping with modern-day thinking on equality”.</p>



<p></p>
",
```

My question is, how do you handle the

tags so that the return line white space is managable?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your css:

```
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

And just replace 0 with whatever suits (0.5rem, 20px, whatever floats your boat really).

Comment: That would work fine for react, but react native, it doesn't work, as I'm not rendering HTML inside a HTML pane, its being loaded in <Text></Text>